# Postgis : Query to get list of multiple neighbour polygon which area sum equal to 42

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm finally asking a question for this because it's been days I'm on it!

My problem is the following one :
In my database, I have a lot of polygons which are in the same region. I'm trying to create a query for 3 polygons which let me know all possibilities where 3 polygons are neighbour AND the sum of their 3 areas is superior to 41 and inferior to 43 (example)

I already got it for 2 polygons but all my tries for 3 polygons have been a failure, I can get a result but I have to wait way too long (a few hours sometimes ). However, with 2 polygons it can be a few seconds ...
I'm running my script on my server (12 core and 64 RAM)

Here is the code I was using for 3 polygons search ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p1.id As p1_id, p2.id As p2_id, p3.id As p3_id
FROM table1 As p1, table1 As p2, table1 As p3
WHERE 
    p1.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p2.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p3.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p1.id <> p2.id
    AND p1.id <> p3.id
    AND p2.id <> p3.id 
    AND ((ST_Area(p1.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p2.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p3.polygon) * 0.67) > 41.0)
    AND ((ST_Area(p1.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p2.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p3.polygon) * 0.67) < 43.0)
    AND (
    (ST_DWithin(p1.polygon, p2.polygon, 1.0, true) AND ST_DWithin(p2.polygon, p3.polygon, 1.0, true))
      OR (ST_DWithin(p1.polygon, p3.polygon, 1.0, true) AND ST_DWithin(p3.polygon, p2.polygon, 1.0, true)) 
      OR (ST_DWithin(p2.polygon, p1.polygon, 1.0, true) AND ST_DWithin(p1.polygon, p3.polygon, 1.0, true))
     )
LIMIT 10;
```

Any advice or help is welcome!

Another info: my goal was to be able to generate this kind of query for X number of polygons

Thank's and have a nice day

##################################
Edit

As asked by Jim, here is an example

We suppose this region with 11 polygons:

We are looking for 3 polygons which are neighbour and sum area equal to 7
In this case, I suppose 3 solutions exist:

1. P2-P3-P11
2. P3-P11-p10
3. P4-P10-P11

For the last one, it's only an intersect on the point, I'm not sure I will keep this result later, it will maybe 2 points at least to be considered (by this I'm avoiding angle ..)

[image]

```
P1 = POLYGON(( 0.0 0.0, 0.0 1.0, 1.0 1.0, 1.0 0.0 ))
P2 = POLYGON(( 1.0 0.0, 1.0 1.0, 3.0 1.0, 3.0 0.0 ))
P3 = POLYGON(( 3.0 0.0, 3.0 2.0, 4.0 2.0, 4.0 0.0 ))
P4 = POLYGON(( 0.0 1.0, 0.0 3.0, 1.0 3.0, 1.0 1.0 ))
P5 = POLYGON(( 1.0 1.0, 1.0 2.0, 2.0 2.0, 2.0 1.0 ))
P6 = POLYGON(( 2.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0, 3.0 2.0, 3.0 1.0 ))
P7 = POLYGON(( 1.0 2.0, 1.0 3.0, 2.0 3.0, 2.0 2.0 ))
P8 = POLYGON(( 2.0 2.0, 2.0 3.0, 3.0 3.0, 3.0 2.0 ))
P9 = POLYGON(( 0.0 3.0, 0.0 4.0, 1.0 4.0, 1.0 3.0 ))
P10 = POLYGON(( 1.0 3.0, 1.0 4.0, 3.0 4.0, 3.0 3.0 ))
P11 = POLYGON(( 3.0 2.0, 3.0 5.0, 4.0 5.0, 4.0 2.0 ))
```

So for a multipolygon:

```
MULTIPOLYGON((( 0.0 0.0, 0.0 1.0, 1.0 1.0, 1.0 0.0 )),
(( 1.0 0.0, 1.0 1.0, 3.0 1.0, 3.0 0.0 )),
(( 3.0 0.0, 3.0 2.0, 4.0 2.0, 4.0 0.0 )),
(( 0.0 1.0, 0.0 3.0, 1.0 3.0, 1.0 1.0 )),
(( 1.0 1.0, 1.0 2.0, 2.0 2.0, 2.0 1.0 )),
(( 2.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0, 3.0 2.0, 3.0 1.0 )),
(( 1.0 2.0, 1.0 3.0, 2.0 3.0, 2.0 2.0 )),
(( 2.0 2.0, 2.0 3.0, 3.0 3.0, 3.0 2.0 )),
(( 0.0 3.0, 0.0 4.0, 1.0 4.0, 1.0 3.0 )),
(( 1.0 3.0, 1.0 4.0, 3.0 4.0, 3.0 3.0 )),
(( 3.0 2.0, 3.0 5.0, 4.0 5.0, 4.0 2.0 )))
```

I hope I haven't made a mistake on coordinates.
Thank's everyone for the differents answer :D

Comment: Could you also add a data sample and if possible the expected result? Cheers

Comment: btw, don't be surprised if it takes too long to finally get the result 42 ;-)

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but I would break it down. Create a table of all touching polygon pairs by region, then add a column filled with ids that appear in the table as touching both pairs. (So a touches b, find c which touches a and b). Do your area calculation on that.

Comment: Oh, and add an "explain analyse" to your question? Bet it's the st_dwithin statements that slow it down...

Comment: @JimJones 7.5 million years run time?

Comment: @mlinth at best! :-D

Comment: @JimJones it's a possibility we can't be sure what the universe has for us haha                             And yes I thought the st_dwithin is slowing down the all. The idea with this was to verify if the next polygon is a neighbour, what would you use? I thought of ST_Touches which seems quicker                                                                                                        And thank's guys for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3, we can say that a central polygon is connected to 2 others. I would focus on finding this central polygon. It will eventually lead to duplicates (if the 3 polygons touch each others) that you would have to filter out.

Also make sure to have an index on `st_area(geom)` or to pre-compute it. (In fact, a multi-column index on `id, region, st_area(geom)` should be the most efficient)

Most importantly, have a spatial index.

```
SELECT
    p1.id As p1_id, p2.id As p2_id, p3.id As p3_id
FROM table1 As p1
 JOIN table1 As p2 ON ST_DWithin(p1.polygon, p2.polygon, 1.0, true)
 JOIN table1 As p3 ON ST_DWithin(p1.polygon, p3.polygon, 1.0, true)
WHERE 
    p1.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p2.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p3.region_id IN (17) 
    AND p1.id <> p2.id
    AND p1.id <> p3.id
    AND p2.id <> p3.id 
    AND ((ST_Area(p1.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p2.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p3.polygon) * 0.67) > 41.0)
    AND ((ST_Area(p1.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p2.polygon) * 0.67 + ST_Area(p3.polygon) * 0.67) < 43.0
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! Yes, I thought of using the central polygon but this will be useful only for 3 polygons if I want to use it for 4 polygons it has to be a lot different. Great idea for pre-compute st_area, I will try and I'm going to see for the spatial index! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Think I have a scaleable solution... If we union touching polygons we only ever have the case of comparing two polygons. And if we know which polygons touch, we can just track touching polygons in an array of the polygon ids.

I use [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) to sort the ids:

```
Create extension intarray;
alter table polygons add id_array  int[];
update polygons set id_array = array[id];
create index polygons_geom on polygons using gist(geom);
```

---

EDIT - use select distinct on rather than a group by, and building on @JGH's point, we can do the spatial calculations once, then lookup in the array

---

Pre-calculate the touching polygons and the areas, then you don't need any further spatial calculations.

```
alter table polygons add geom_area  numeric;
update polygons set geom_area = st_area(geom);


create table touching_pairs as
select  a.id as a_id,a.id_array, b.id as b_id from polygons a
inner join polygons b on st_touches(a.geom, b.geom);
create index touching_pairs_id on touching_pairs(a_id);
```

Now find touching polygons. These are ids that touch one of the ids already in the array that is itself not in the array. Add that to the array and add up the areas.

```
create table pairs as
select distinct on(sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc'))  p.geom_area + a.geom_area as geom_area,
sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') as id_array
 from polygons p -- only need to change this!
 inner join touching_pairs t
 on t.b_id = any(p.id_array) and t.a_id != all(p.id_array)
 inner join polygons a on a.id = t.a_id
 order by sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') , t.b_id;
```

You can then use the same query, just with the pairs...

```
 create table trios as
select distinct on(sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc'))  p.geom_area + a.geom_area as geom_area,
sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') as id_array
 from pairs p -- only need to change this!
 inner join touching_pairs t
 on t.b_id = any(p.id_array) and t.a_id != all(p.id_array)
 inner join polygons a on a.id = t.a_id
 order by sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') , t.b_id;
```

Then:

```
select * from trios where geom_area = 7;
```

Gives you;

```
{2,3,11}
{3,10,11}
{4,10,11}
```

Quartets...

```
select distinct on(sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc'))  p.geom_area + a.geom_area as geom_area,
sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') as id_array
 from trios p -- only need to change this!
 inner join touching_pairs t
 on t.b_id = any(p.id_array) and t.a_id != all(p.id_array)
 inner join polygons a on a.id = t.a_id
 order by sort(p.id_array || t.id_array,'asc') , t.b_id;
```

I think that this is the fastest way. Just ran it on 491 polygons in a few seconds.

Comment: Interesting approach!  I guess the st_contains clause could be replaced by a faster ID comparison (b.id not in a.id_array)

Comment: Hi Guys , @mlinth you rock ! What a great approach , I'm currently trying to implement it , I will let you know how it's work ;) thank's again , have a great day !